# Why does console.log log strings with quotes in some cases?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, types

I am running these examples of Node.js v10.5.0. When I only print strings with it, it prints the strings without surrounding quotes.

```
> console.log('foo', 'bar')
foo bar
undefined
```

But when I print strings and numbers together, then it prints strings with surrounding quotes.

```
> console.log(1, 'foo', 'bar')
1 'foo' 'bar'
undefined
```

Why does this difference occur? I was expecting it to print the following in the second example:

```
1 foo bar
```

Similar behavior can be observed with Chrome 70.

It looks like `console.log()` chooses to show string in quotes when there are arguments of number type but then these examples print all strings without quotes even when numbers are involved:

```
> console.log('foo', 'bar', 1)
foo bar 1
undefined
> console.log('foo', 1, 'bar')
foo 1 bar
undefined
```

What's going on here? Why does `console.log()` print strings with quotes in some cases and not in other cases?

Comment: You wouldn't know if `1` was string or number then would you? Note different browsers also handle this differently

Comment: @charlietfl I wouldn't in that case. That's right. But if I wanted to know the type, I could do something like `console.log(1, typeof 1, 'foo', typeof 'foo')`. Is it `console.log()`'s responsibility to show me the types by default?

Comment: is probably doing that out of convenience when you pass in different types

Comment: It seems to me that in the specific case where all arguments are strings, `console.log` outputs the concatenated, unquoted string. If any argument is not a string, you get individual quoted strings.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I thought so but here is a counterexample: `console.log('foo', 'bar', 1)`. This prints `foo bar 1` (without any quotes).

Comment: @charlietfl For some reason it decides not to offer that convenience in case of `console.log('foo', 1, 'bar')` even if there are different types. In this case, it prints all arguments without quotes like `foo 1 bar`.

Comment: So why does it even matter? Console rendering is different across environments and there is no real standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a legitimate standard yet for `console.log` but most browsers, including Chrome (i.e. Chromium), use the [working group specification (WHATWG)](https://github.com/whatwg/console):

https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger

According to this spec, if you have differing numbers of parameters then different methods are used to output the data, according to the current specification:

**2.1 Logger(logLevel, args)**

1. If *args* is empty, return.
2. Let *first* be `args[0]`.
3. Let *rest* be all elements following first in args.
4. If *rest* is empty, perform `Printer(logLevel, « first »)` and return.
5. If *first* does not contain any format specifiers, perform
   `Printer(logLevel, args)`.
6. Otherwise, perform `Printer(logLevel, Formatter(args))`.
7. Return `undefined`.

Ultimately, the number of parameters determine the methods that are used to output information.  Specifically, in your example the first parameter can not contain a format specifier because it's a number so it gets passed to [Printer()](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer) but if the first parameter is a string then it gets passed to [Formatter()](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter).

So, you get different output depending on order:

```
> console.log('hello',1,'hello')
hello 1 hello
```

versus

```
> console.log(1,'hello','hello')
1 "hello" "hello"
```

Ultimately, how those methods output information is implementation/browser dependent:

> How the implementation prints args is up to the implementation, but
>   implementations should separate the objects by a space or something
>   similar, as that has become a developer expectation.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a deliberate choice by the Chrome team. There is no standard for how console.log works in different environments.